# Spring boot CrudRepo Save() method is not merging the existing entry, but it's replacing

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot with Mysql. Whenever I call save method from the CrudRepository, it replaces the entity from the table. I want it to merge the new entity in the existing entity in table.

What am I doing wrong here?

eg. Entry in DB:  id=12345, firstName=foo, lastName=bar

Calling save with new Entity: id=12345, firstName=doe

After the save operation, db has, id=12345, firstName=doe, **lastName=null**

My entity class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity

public class Branch {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private String latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private String longitude;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BranchType branchType;
}
```

My Repo:

```
public interface BranchRepo extends CrudRepository<Branch, String> {

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-url
spring.datasource.username=user-name-here
spring.datasource.password=password-name-here
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.Defau‌​ltNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
```

Comment: if you don't set the field lastName it will be null.
the implementation will fetch the corresponding entity from db and check for differences and update accordingly. E.g. call save on new Entity: id=12345, firstName=doe, lastName=bar
OR simply findOne(12345) and update the field you need to update

Comment: Do you mean, there's no direct way in spring-data-jpa to update only some of the fields from the entity? On every occurrence fetching from DB, merging it with entity  and putting it back in the db is too much of duplication of code. 

Also, in the logs, I can see three queries getting fired as a part of single save() operation.  First, it checks whether entity exists(), then it fetches entity from the db, last it replaces entry in the db by the entity being passed.

If spring-jpa anyway dis-regards the existing entity from db, it's confusing why it fires three queries in save() operation.

Comment: not that i know of, but i may be wrong (that's why was a comment and not answer). anyway afaik its not replacing, it is fetching, checking difference and updating all different field to the db. essentially making the entity in the persistence the final one

Comment: there is updatable, insertable annotation but that would make jpa ignore that entity field always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main concern was to not to force developer to explicitly handle update operation by calling findOne() and then merging two objects and then calling save().

As spring data doesn't support it out of the box, i needed to add this functionality to our API platform.

First I tried to extend the behavior of JpaRepository to override the save() method. but as its an interface, I couldn't update this behavior.

I ended up creating a EntityMergingService, which accepts two entities, one from the DB and one from in Memory. It then uses reflection to do the null checking and do the merging.

The caller party has responsibility to call, findOne(), call merge from above service and then call save().

This way, we don't have to write multiple merging methods for each entity. This is not the best approach, what would be better is, if I could override the save() method from JPA Repository. Which will internally do, findOne(), and merging and save merged object.

Answer (score 0):

To 'update' entity you must:

1. Retrieve it from DB:

```java
Branch branch = branchRepo.findOne("12345");
```

2. Update its fields:

```java
branch.setName("Updated Name");
branch.setAddress("Updated Address");
```

3. Save this entity:

```java
branchRepo.save(branch);
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to go this way you can use '[modifying queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)'. In this way you have to define a set of updated fields in every query:

```java
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update Branch b set b.name = ?1 where b.id = ?2")
int updateName(String name, String id);

@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update Branch b set b.name = ?1, b.address = ?2 where b.id = ?3")
int updateNameAndAddress(String name, Address address, String id);

// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I just added comment to my question. Same comment applies here.

Comment: This will force user to create different method for different combinations of entity properties that might need to be updated which is not practical.

Comment: Of course it will if you don't like the first approach.